# Oil price cutting or cutting oil prices

Tags: word-order

Which of these is correct and why?

The inflation in commodity was led by **oil price cutting**

or

The inflation in commodity was led by **cutting oil prices**

Comment: If you cut prices, there is no inflation.....inflation comes from **raising** prices or demand.

Comment: @Lambie Good point, that is true. I guess the questions is more about the use of 'oil price cutting' or 'cutting oil prices' - the latter seems the better one to me.

Comment: Cutting oil prices is not something OPEC usually does.